# Is there an objective-c specific way to count bits in an integer

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation

I'd like to count the bits set to 1 in my 32-bit integer in objective-c.  Some languages have this as a single call:

- Java has Integer.bitCount()
- C++ sometimes has __popcount()
- SQL has BIT_COUNT()

Is there an equivalent for Objective-C?  Otherwise I'll use :

```
-(int32_t) BitCounter:(int32_t) v
{
    v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((v + (v >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

...which is fine, but some processors have it as a single command built in to the processor and naturally I'd like to take advantage of that since it's in a time critical loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc, clang *et al* have [__builtin_popcount](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), which is a C built-in which can be called from Objective-C:

```
-(int32_t) BitCounter:(int32_t) v
{
    return __builtin_popcount(v);
}
```

On a modern x86 platform with SSE 4.2 this should compile to a single instruction (`POPCNT`).

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, thanks.  I'll actually dispense with the function and use it directly.

Comment: For some reason, my Xcode (with Swift 2.2) doesn't recognise this function. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @TimVermeulen: it's probably not available in Swift - only C/C++/Objective-C et al.

Comment: @PaulR And I thought all functions from C were bridged automatically... Interesting.

Comment: @TimVermeulen: ah, but it's not a function, it's an intrinsic. Intrinsics typically generate inline machine instructions (usually just one instruction, sometimes more). This kind of thing doesn't fit very well with high level languages like Swift. If Swift supports linking with C libraries though then you could just wrap the intrinsic as per above and call it from your Swift code ?